# Can I develop for ASP.net 4.6 after installing ASP.net Core 1 update?

Tags: asp.net

At my job we're developing with the ASP.net framework. Unfortunately I updated to ASP.net Core 1 by a mistake on my computer. Can I still work with code made for previous versions of ASP.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I still work with code made for previous versions of ASP.net ?

Yes, I have exactly the same situation like you - I have installed Update 3 for VS, .NET Framework 4.6.1 and ASP.NET Core... and my project is ASP.NET 4.5 - everything works well.

ASP.NET Core is installed next to ASP.NET Framework and not replace it.

You have project templates for both, you can create new project for both and still you can develop your old project.

Comment: That's great. I'm glad to hear that.